# one-liner xpath extraction command line tool

Tags: xml, command-line, lxml

```
...
<div class="article_header">
...
<a href="abc" title="PDF">XXX</a>
...
</div>
...
```

Given the above XML, I'd like to just print "abc". I could use lxml in python to do so. But that involves making a python program. I'd like something more like one liner (just like awk one liner is simple to process TSV file than python) to extract short information like this.

Is there a tool that can do this? Can somebody show me what is the simplest way to do so?

Comment: How about making a Python program that does what you're describing - take an input and an XPath and output the result? Asking for tool recommendations or other off-site resources is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifically says that questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, software library or other off-site resource are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). It's a linux command line tool to query XML files.
For your example, use

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//div[@class='article_header']/a/@href" input.xml
```

Output is:

> abc

Comment: I got this error `Entity 'nbsp' not defined` when I try html files. How make it aware of HTML files? Also some error like this: `: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     ^`

Comment: [`&nbsp;`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) is not a standard XML entity, it's an HTML entity. You tagged your question as XML and `xmlstarlet` is not an HTML utility. So, sorry, that doesn't work.

Comment: Your second error "XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document" is caused by spaces before the XML declaration. Remove the spaces and the error will disappear.

Comment: Is there a tool to prefilter the input so that it will become valid for xmlstarlet? It seems that xmlstarlet is too sensitive too error. lxml isn't like this.